# Git completion fails after updating to Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish

Tags: bash, git, auto-completion

I recently updated to Ubuntu 18.10 and after that my `git completion` has been failing.

Bash is able to complete the first command successfully, for example (I'll use ↬ to indicate TAB was used)

```
$ ala↬
$ alacritty
```

But when I use tab to complete a git command it fails.

```
$ git stat↬
$ git status #should be
$ git statunknown option: --list-cmds=list-mainporcelain,others,nohelpers,alias,list-complete,config
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
       [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
       [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
       [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
       <command> [<args>]
```

I've tried reinstalling `bash-completion`

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall bash-completion
```

Check if it was some issue in my `~/.bashrc` [Link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2393044)

Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling git? Might seem like a neanderthal solution, but do try "sudo apt-get purge git" and then "sudo apt-get install git". Hope that works. Ciao :)

Comment: @thephoenix01 `git` is working as expected, but I tried your suggestion anyway. But I still have issues with git-completion

Comment: [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327817/git-completion-bash-producing-error-on-macos-sierra-10-12-6) could be something I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was answered on a different StackExchange site. [Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327817/git-completion-bash-producing-error-on-macos-sierra-10-12-6) is the answer.

The reason I was having issues with my `git-completion` is that when I updated by Ubuntu it replaced the `git-completion` file found in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git` with a version that needed `git v2.18` and I have v2.17.1. The problem is that none of the package managers have updated to git v2.18 yet.

So I just replaced my git-completions file with the appropriate version found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/v2.17.1/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash).

Works as expected!